# Use redactor as a vue component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, redactor

I am trying to use redactor as a vuejs 2 component but I am having lots of trouble because once loaded redactor creates a new div so I am not able to listen to a keyup event on that div. Please see the code I have below.

**Vue Component**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <textarea @keyup="internalValue" class="form-control question-create-editor" id="question_description" placeholder="Go wild with all the details here - make image upload work" rows="3">
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    props: ['value'],
    data () {
      return {
        internalValue: this.value
      }
    },
    mounted: function(){
      $(function() {
        // $( document ).ready(function() {
          $('#question-create-form .question-create-editor').redactor({
            imageUpload:'/urlGoesHereBro/',
            plugins: ['video', 'imagemanager', 'counter', 'limiter'],
            buttonsHide:['html', 'formatting', 'deleted', 'indent', 'outdent', 'alignment', 'horizontalrule']
          });
          $('#question-create-form .redactor-editor').attr('v-model', 'questionDescription');
        // });
      });
    },
    watch: {
      internalValue(v){
        this.$emit($('.redactor-editor').html(), v);
      }
    }
};
</script>
```

**Register Component**

```
Vue.component('vueredactor', require('./components/redactor-qa.vue'));
```

**Initialise VUE**

```
var App = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
          questionDescription: null
        }
    });
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="app">
  <vueredactor v-model="questionDescription"></vueredactor>
</div>
```

Comment: There's lots that goes into properly wrapping a widget. This will be a learning adventure for you. :) Instead of using document-level jQuery selectors, use `this.$el` as your top-level DOM element. Refer here: https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#mounted

Comment: Thanks for the info, I'll begin my new adventure :)

Comment: For anyone having the same issue, see the answer in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43035340/jquery-plugin-in-vue-component-cannot-pass-value-to-prop/43035433?noredirect=1#43035433

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the new div, you *can* listen to events on it, but not by applying Vue attributes. Because you are inside the component, you can use jQuery to find elements, attach listeners to them, and any other DOM manipulations that make sense to bridge between Vue and your widget. Just confine yourself to elements inside your component.

Vue gives you a `$el` member (don't be fooled by the dollar sign, it's not a jQuery object) as the root element of your component instance. I don't have any experience with redactor, so I can't tell you what will work, but you might have *something like*

```
mounted: function(){
  $(function() {
      $(this.$vm).find('.question-create-editor').redactor({
        imageUpload:'/urlGoesHereBro/',
        plugins: ['video', 'imagemanager', 'counter', 'limiter'],
        buttonsHide:['html', 'formatting', 'deleted', 'indent', 'outdent', 'alignment', 'horizontalrule']
      });
      $(this.$vm).find('.new-redactor-div').keyup((e) => {
        this.$emit('change', e);
      });
  });
},
```